# if i delete search service application from Central admin the whole components will delete?

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search

In a sharepoint farm there is a search service application and its components deployed in two application servers.

If I delete search service application from Central admin the whole components will delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ideal environment, it should delete but exceptions are always there.So it is recommended that once you delete the Service Application then manually check everything gone.

- Make Sure Search Related Database deleted from SQL Server
- Make Sure the Search Service Application proxy connection deleted
- App Pool related to Search Service Deleted
- Delete the Index file on the server
- Stop the search service

read more over here http://blog.greenbrain.de/2013/11/removing-corrupted-search-service-from.html

Comment: when i try to delete from CA i got this error Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (0e8bab9b-bb02-41cd-8d3a-b979a9f3fe5a).

Reason: No active topology exists for : Portal Search Application

Comment: use powershell or stsadm ...https://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/deleting-the-search-service-application/

Comment: i used powershell now to delete and i got below errors The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.IndexingScheduleJobDefinition (ID ae5101de-7d2b-42e8-b04a-7e67a4310fcb) threw an exception. More information is included below.

databaseConnectionString

Comment: i think start a new thread and give us the full details, then it will be helpful